# Entity Framework returns different result with AsNoTracking

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, linq

I use Entity Framework in combination with an Oracle database. If I create a query like

```
myLinqStatement.ToListAsync()
```

I get wrong data returned as a result. If I change the statement to

```
myLinqStatement.AsNoTracking.ToListAsync()
```

I get the correct data.

I also checked the native SQL query, which is generated by `myLinqStatement.ToListAsync()`. The generated SQL query is correct, because I get the correct data.

So is there a problem in the mapping? And why is it working with `AsNoTracking`?

Thanks!

Comment: What does "wrong data" mean? No data at all? Can you also include the whole code containing `.ToListAsync` without the `AsNoTracking`?

Comment: Most likely incorrect PK mapping of database view.

Comment: The result count is the same - but the data are different. For example: I have a column/property "RES_NAME" which have different data in the two results

Answer (score 2):

What `AsNoTracking` does is to retrieve the data without attaching it to the context, hence any changes you apply over the data do not take effect unless you attach it again so that EF knows it should track its changes.

The code snippets you've provided do not show the whole picture, from the moment a context is created, but is it possible that other parts of your code mutate data before you call `myLinqStatement.ToListAsync()`?

As you mention that `myLinqStatement.AsNoTracking.ToListAsync()` returns expected data, makes me assume that there are some side effects in your code that `AsNoTracking` simply is not aware so just returns whatever it finds in your db

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I had a similar issue with Entity Framework Core querying a DB view, the issue was cause because view didn't have a key defined, after defining a key for the entity that map to that DB view, the query returned the same result in both cases (using AsNoTracking or without using it).
In T-SQL a key for a DB view can be defined this way:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX UQ_MyDBViewName_ColumnKey
   ON dbo.MyDBViewName (ColumnKey);
```

And in code, you can map the key using the `[Key]` attribute in the corresponding property of the entity or using the EF fluent API. It will depend of what the project is using.

Either way, using AsNoTracking on a query that goes directly to a DB view makes a lot of sense. Also, if for some reason the query of the view does not allow us to define a key for that view, then the option is to use AsNoTracking.

Hope it helps anyone else having the same issue.